# How to join array with table(Link ID in array with table ID)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, join

So, I have a database with a list. The items in the list has a user_id attached to them and I have done a query to count them and group them but since I have done this in `DB::Select` and raw SQL the relation from the `user_id` to the actual user has been lost.

I have been trying with a join, but so far no luck, here is my code:

This gets me the list with a `number(count)` and the `user_id`.

```
$updatedToday = DB::select('SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM faulty_device WHERE DATE(`updated_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND (status = 3 OR status = 4 OR status = 5) GROUP BY user_id');
```

This is not working, see my try of a join :

```
$updatedToday = DB::select('SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM faulty_device JOIN users ON faulty_device.user_id=users.id WHERE DATE(`updated_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND (status = 3 OR status = 4 OR status = 5) GROUP BY user_id');
```

What I want to do is basically use this in my view:

```
@foreach($updatedToday as $updated)
    {{$updated->user->username}}
    {{$updated->num}}
@endforeach
```

(Showing etc username: Ted Swansson, num: 15)

But so far I can only manage to get this to work:

```
@foreach($updatedToday as $updated)
    {{$updated->user_id}}
    {{$updated->num}}
@endforeach
```

(Showing etc user_id: 5, num: 15)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**EDIT**

I made it work in phpmyadmin, but the same command fails in laravel....

```
SELECT user_id, username, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM faulty_device JOIN users ON faulty_device.user_id=users.id WHERE DATE(`updated_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND (status = 3 OR status = 4 OR status = 5) GROUP BY user_id
```

Says :

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'database1.users.username'
>   isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT user_id, username, COUNT(*) AS `num`
>   FROM faulty_device JOIN users ON faulty_device.user_id=users.id WHERE
>   DATE(`updated_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND
>   (status = 3 OR status = 4 OR status = 5) GROUP BY user_id)

**EDIT 2** 
Laravel wanted an additional GROUP BY, it is now resolved.

Comment: Shouldn't the `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS num` include `username` as well? Maybe use a left join perhaps?

Comment: Well, the username is in another table so the only thing that gets listed currently is the user_id and the num. Will check this left join out.

Comment: Left join returns nothing more atm, might be doing it wrong tho.. Still getting :

array:6 [▼
  0 => {#427 ▼
    +"user_id": 1
    +"num": 2
  }
  1 => {#187 ▼
    +"user_id": 3
    +"num": 3
  }
  2 => {#429 ▼
    +"user_id": 13
    +"num": 8
  }
  3 => {#428 ▼
    +"user_id": 14
    +"num": 5
  }
  4 => {#432 ▼
    +"user_id": 16
    +"num": 4
  }
  5 => {#433 ▼
    +"user_id": 27
    +"num": 30
  }
]

Comment: When you join it will be included and will be there if you `SELECT` it. Like `SELECT user_id, username, COUNT(*) AS num`

Comment: But, the username is in another table, to be joined through the user_id?

I tried your following, but still no luck:

$updatedToday = DB::select('SELECT user_id, username COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM faulty_device LEFT JOIN users ON faulty_device.user_id=users.id WHERE DATE(`updated_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND (status = 3 OR status = 4 OR status = 5) GROUP BY user_id');

Comment: Is it in the `users` table? Did you miss a `,` in `user_id, username COUNT(...`?

Comment: username is in the users table, this is the faulty_device table, no missed ',' as far as i can tell, sadly.

Comment: Updated the question, got it working in phpmyadmin, but not laravel. Which is odd.

Comment: Your SELECT user_id, username, COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY user_id is wrong... read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: I can see that, got it fixed about 2 minutes ago. Strange how it worked in PHPMYADMIN without the GROUP BY username aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It wanted an "username" at the end as an additional GROUP BY.

```
SELECT user_id, username, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM faulty_device LEFT JOIN users ON faulty_device.user_id=users.id WHERE DATE(`updated_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND (status = 3 OR status = 4 OR status = 5) GROUP BY user_id, username
```